# Can't get IOS app to compile in Xcode - works fine on android emulator

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, podfile

I have a React native App that works well on android emulator no issue. Now I am trying to test it out on an IOS emulator but I keep getting compile errors. I am very new to Xcode and I tried to follow the directions exactly. Tried a lot of recommendations through other questions and keep getting compile errors. Can someone please tell me what I am missing - there has to be an obvious reason that this keeps failing to compile. For what it is worth, before I integrated Firebase, the IOS emulator worked fine but when I tried to integrate with the sdk is when it failed.
Here are my relevant files:

Podfile:

`

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static


target 'MyHomeProject' do
  config = use_native_modules!

#Installing pods
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'


  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => true,
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.

    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'MyHomeProjectTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <React_RCTAppDelegate/RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
  #import "AppDelegate.h"
  #import <React/RCTBridge.h>
  #import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

  #import <Firebase.h>

  @implementation AppDelegate

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {

    [FIRApp configure];

   self.moduleName = @"MyHomeProject";
   self.initialProps = @{};

   bool didFinish = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];


   return didFinish;
   }

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

For some reason it is not letting add the image of the errors so here are some of the compile build errors:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk/usr/include/os/_workgroup.h:34:10 Could not build module 'os_workgroup'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h:16:10 Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:18:10 Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:18:10 Could not build module 'CoreFoundation'`

Lots of errors like one above that seem to come from the .h file.

Then errors like this for my main file --> Could not build module 'UIKit'. `

Here is my main file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
 }
}
```

Any help would be so so appreciated, I have spent so many hours on this!

Answer (score 0):

in your `AppDelegate.m` import  `#import <Firebase.h>` at the top of the file

its mentioned [here](https://rnfirebase.io/#configure-firebase-with-ios-credentials)

Comment: Hi I tried that right after I posted this, exact same errors:(